# TensorflowLite error: Didn't find op for builtin opcode 'WHERE' version '1'

Tags: tensorflow, arduino, operators, tensorflow-lite, tflite

I would like to run the model that I made on the Arduino BLE 33 board(nRF52840)
while uploading to board using ArduinoIDE below massage appeared

> Didn't find op for builtin opcode 'WHERE' version '1'. An older version of this builtin might be supported. Are you using an old TFLite binary with a newer model?
> Failed to get registration from op code WHERE
> AllocateTensors() failed
> Invoke failed!

**Does anyone know how to solve the problem?**

I am new to TensorFlow and studying it. Please someone who has gone through help me.

---

**my version status**

tensorflow==2.8.0
TensorFlow Lite Micro Library `git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-micro-arduino-examples Arduino_TensorFlowLite`
Arduino IDE 2.2.1

**What I been through..**

I converted to .tflite file and changed to model.h and model.cc with below code

```
!echo "const unsigned char model[] = {" > /content/model.h
!cat gesture_model.tflite | xxd -i      >> /content/model.h
!echo "};"                              >> /content/model.h

import os
model_h_size = os.path.getsize("model.h")
print(f"Header file, model.h, is {model_h_size:,} bytes.")
print("\nOpen the side panel (refresh if needed). Double click model.h to download the file.")
```

**Trial 0) Using `AllOpsResolver`**

The error appeared.

> Didn't find op for builtin opcode 'WHERE' version '1'. An older version of this builtin might be supported. Are you using an old TFLite binary with a newer model?
> Failed to get registration from op code WHERE
> AllocateTensors() failed
> Invoke failed!

**Trial 1) Using `MicroMutableOpResolver` instead of `AllOpsResolver`**

However, there is no `AddWhere()` function to add the WHERE op to the MicroMutableOpResolver.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-micro/blob/main/tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_mutable_op_resolver.h

```
static tflite::MicroMutableOpResolver<17> micro_op_resolver;
  micro_op_resolver.AddPad();
  micro_op_resolver.AddReshape();
  micro_op_resolver.AddConv2D();
  micro_op_resolver.AddTranspose();
  micro_op_resolver.AddMaxPool2D();
  micro_op_resolver.AddWhile();
  micro_op_resolver.AddConcatenation();
  micro_op_resolver.AddEqual();
  //micro_op_resolver.AddWhere();  // no function
  micro_op_resolver.AddGather();
  micro_op_resolver.AddShape();
  micro_op_resolver.AddCast();
  //micro_op_resolver.AddSparseToDense();  // no function
  micro_op_resolver.AddAdd();
  micro_op_resolver.AddStridedSlice();
  micro_op_resolver.AddPack();
  micro_op_resolver.AddFullyConnected();
  micro_op_resolver.AddLess();
  micro_op_resolver.AddIf();

// Build an interpreter to run the model with.
  static tflite::MicroInterpreter static_interpreter(
    model, micro_op_resolver, tensor_arena, kTensorArenaSize);
```

The following error masseges printed

> MicroAllocator: Model allocation started before finishing the previously allocated model
> Failed starting model allocation.
> Invoke failed!

FYI) The model uses 19 OPs as shown in the above-mentioned code.

**Trial 2) Does TF Lite not support the WHERE op?**

It seems that the answer is NO. If you see the below link, there is the explanation of tfl.where and tfl.sparse_to_dense.
https://www.tensorflow.org/mlir/tfl_ops?hl=ko#tflwhere_tflwhereop

**Trial 3) The OP Version Problem?**

I've checked the op version info of this link
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/tools/versioning/runtime_version.cc

```
{{BuiltinOperator_WHERE, 1}, "1.14.0"}
{{BuiltinOperator_WHERE, 2}, "2.8.0"},
```

I think this is the problem. However, I can not find a way to modify the version that the model uses.

It would be helpful if someone comments about what I did. Thankyou!

Thank you in advance.